# How to combine data from rows to columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

i am having structure like this. Trying to create dynamic table

```
create table indicator(id int not null,name varchar(255) not null)
insert indicator (id, name) values (1, 'basic employee details')

create table fields(
id int identity(1,1) not null,  
type int,
name varchar(255) not null,
parentid int not null)

insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (1, 1, 'year', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (2, 2, '2010', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (5, 2, '2011', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (6, 2, '2012', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (7, 2, '2013', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (8, 2, '2014', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (9, 1, 'nationality', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (10, 1, 'bahrani', 9)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (11, 1, 'non bahrani', 9)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (12, 1, 'gender', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (13, 1, 'male', 12)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (14, 1, 'fe male', 12)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (15, 1, 'maritalstatus', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (16, 1, 'married', 15)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (17, 1, 'unmarried', 15)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (18, 1, 'divorced', 15)

create table datafields(
    dataid int not null,
    fieldid int not null)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 2)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 13)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 16)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 5)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 14)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 17)


create table indicatorfields(
indicatorid int not null,
fieldid int not null)

insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 5)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 6)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 7)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 8)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 10)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 11)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 13)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 14)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 16)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 17)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 18)

create table indicatordata(
dataid int not null,
value varchar(255) not null,
indicatorid int not null) 

insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (1, '1015', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (2, '12', 1)
```

I got the output like this

[image]

**I am trying to get the data similar to like this**

[image]

Since i am trying with the pivot concept...

guide me to get generate table similar to like this

**I tried with this, not getting expected output**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000),@cols NVARCHAR(4000),@groupid varchar(50)

set @groupid='1'
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + name + ']','[' + name + ']')
FROM    Fields where parentid=0
--ORDER BY name

SET @query = N'SELECT id, '+@cols +'
FROM
(
select d.dataid as id,b.name,e.value FROm IndicatorFields a INNER JOIN fields b On a.fieldid=b.id INNER JOIN fields c ON c.id=b.parentid
INNER JOIN DataFields d  ON a.fieldid=d.fieldid INNER JOIN IndicatorData e ON e.id=d.dataid
and a.indicatorid='+@groupid+') p
PIVOT
(
MAX([value])
FOR name IN
( '+@cols +' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY id;'

print @query
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: thanks  for sample data

Comment: Thanks for the edit with what you've tried - added dynamic SQL to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't post queries as images. Assuming I copied your query correctly, I think this gives you what you are looking for using a `PIVOT`

You can then wrap this in some dynamic sql - there are tons of examples here on SO - use the search.

```
SELECT dataid
,MAX(value) Value
,MAX([Year]) Year
,MAX([Nationality]) Nationality
,MAX([Gender]) Gender
,MAX([MaritalStatus]) MaritalStatus
 FROM 
(SELECT 
      d.dataid
      ,b.name Name1
      ,d.fieldid
      ,c.name Name2
      ,e.value
FROM dbo.indicatorfields a
JOIN dbo.fields b ON a.fieldid = b.id
JOIN dbo.fields c ON b.parentid = c.id
JOIN dbo.datafields d ON a.fieldid = d.fieldid
JOIN dbo.indicatordata e ON e.dataid = d.dataid
)SRC
PIVOT 
(MAX(Name1) FOR Name2 IN ([Year],[Nationality],[Gender], [MaritalStatus]) )PVT
GROUP BY dataid

dataid  Value  Year  Nationality  Gender   MaritalStatus
------  ------ ----- ------------ ------   -------------
1       1015  2010   bahrani      male     married
2       12    2011   non bahrani  fe male  unmarried

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**Edit:**

Dynamic SQL for you based on your try with the above `PIVOT`

```
CREATE table indicator(id int not null,name varchar(255) not null)
insert indicator (id, name) values (1, 'basic employee details')

create table fields(
id int  not null,  
type int,
name varchar(255) not null,
parentid int not null)

insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (1, 1, 'year', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (2, 2, '2010', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (5, 2, '2011', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (6, 2, '2012', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (7, 2, '2013', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (8, 2, '2014', 1)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (9, 1, 'nationality', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (10, 1, 'bahrani', 9)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (11, 1, 'non bahrani', 9)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (12, 1, 'gender', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (13, 1, 'male', 12)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (14, 1, 'fe male', 12)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (15, 1, 'maritalstatus', 0)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (16, 1, 'married', 15)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (17, 1, 'unmarried', 15)
insert fields (id, type, name, parentid) values (18, 1, 'divorced', 15)

create table datafields(
    dataid int not null,
    fieldid int not null)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 2)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 13)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 16)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 5)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 14)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 17)


create table indicatorfields(
indicatorid int not null,
fieldid int not null)

insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 5)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 6)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 7)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 8)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 10)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 11)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 13)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 14)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 16)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 17)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid) values (1, 18)

create table indicatordata(
dataid int not null,
value varchar(255) not null,
indicatorid int not null) 

insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (1, '1015', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (2, '12', 1)



DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000),@cols NVARCHAR(4000),@groupid varchar(50)

set @groupid='1'
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + name + ']','[' + name + ']')
FROM    Fields where parentid=0


DECLARE @sel NVARCHAR(4000);
SELECT  @sel = COALESCE(@sel + ',MAX([' + name + ']) '+name,',MAX([' + name + ']) '+name) FROM  Fields where parentid=0

SET @query = N'SELECT value, dataid' + @Sel +'
     FROM 
    (SELECT 
          d.dataid
          ,b.name Name1
          ,d.fieldid
          ,c.name Name2
          ,e.value
    FROM dbo.indicatorfields a
    JOIN dbo.fields b ON a.fieldid = b.id
    JOIN dbo.fields c ON b.parentid = c.id
    JOIN dbo.datafields d ON a.fieldid = d.fieldid
    JOIN dbo.indicatordata e ON e.dataid = d.dataid
    )SRC
    PIVOT 
    (MAX(Name1) FOR Name2 IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
    GROUP BY dataid, value'

print @query
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: I dont want to define the columns here.. why because all are dynamic... "Year,Nationality,Gender,MaritalStatus" all are dynamic....this wil not work..if i add one more field in future..

Comment: query is not executing..."Kindly check it once & update it"

Comment: Re-tested and re-pasted complete test script, it's working for me. You should have enough here to debug.

Comment: where is the "Value" field data? check my post....how i am trying get output.... you missed value field....

Comment: dataid is correct... but i am not getting expected output.... check this image...how i am trying to get output "http://i.stack.imgur.com/2SZZu.jpg"

Comment: Re-order the cols for you.